# How long can this string of digits be extended?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Consider a number $a_1a_2a_3a_4 \dots a_n$ in some base $b$, such that for each $k, 1\leq k \leq n$, the subnumber $a_1a_2\dots a_k$ is a multiple of $k$.

For instance $1836$ is such a number in base $10$, because $1$ is a multiple of $1$, $18$ is a multiple of $2$, $183$ is a multiple of $3$, and $1836$ is a multiple of $4$.

Let $N(b)$ be the maximum possible value of $n$ for base $b$.

> How large is $N(b)$?

We might expect $N(b)$  to be about $eb$. Indeed, there are about $b^n/n!$ such numbers of length $n$, which by Stirling's approximation goes below $1$ sometime around $n=eb$.

The only lower bound I have is that $N(b)\geq b$. I don't have any upper bound at all.

This question is the result of a conversation with John Conway.

Comment: Is there a good reason why N(b) can't be infinite?

Comment: What does "N(b) > n" mean?

Comment: @Sam, I think it's a typo for $N(b)\gt b$.

Comment: On second thought, is it a typo for $N(b) \ge b$?  Consider $b=2$.  You have to start with $a_1=1$ (otherwise why not let all the $a_i$'s be 0's?), then $a_2=0$ to get $2$ to divide $a_1a_2$, at which point you're done, since $3$ divides neither $4$ nor $5$.

Comment: It's surprisingly quick and easy to find the longest such n by brute force (the number of possibilities of each length doesn't grow much, and for base 10 it never exceeds 2492).  For example, for base 10 the longest is 3608528850368400786036725, which has length 25.  However, this doesn't give a lot of insight into how $N(b)$ depends on $b$.

Comment: Note that every bth digit will need to be 0.  Indeed, I would be surprised to find a base b with N(b)>2b.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Number Games" Paseman, 2013.04.08

Comment: Incidentally, 25 is pretty close to $10e$, in accordance with the heuristic Will Sawin gives.

Comment: OK, 2.5b then.  Gerhard "If Henry Had Been Slower..." Paseman, 2013.04.08

Comment: And I guess you checked the OEIS

Comment: @Barry: I made that calculation, then forgot about it, then convinced myself that $N(b)$ should always be greater than $b$. This has been corrected. @Henry: What tool did you use to make that brute force calculation? @Gerhard: What do you think is problematic about my heuristic? It seems to me that a conspiracy to have more than $b^n/n!$ numbers is as likely as a conspiracy to have less.

Comment: Plugging Henry's number into the OEIS leads to http://oeis.org/A109032 (plus three other entries)

Comment: @Will: I wrote a pari program to compute this. I'm on my cell phone right now but would be happy to send it to you (or anyone else) a bit later this evening.  Send me an email if you're interested.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A109783 is also worth a look.  It notes the finiteness of $N(b)$ (*vide* Toink's comment, above) as one conjecture, and $N(b)\approx eb$ as another.

Comment: Will, it is a pessimistic viewpoint.  If one considers all such numbers arranged in a tree format with the empty string as a root, one notes that at depth b and deeper each node has at most one child node, and that at depth 2b I expect half or fewer of the remaining nodes to have a child.  While your heuristic looks fine, I expect reality to be a little different.  Gerhard "The Glass Is Sized Wrong" Paseman, 2013.04.08

Comment: Nothing you said about the tree contradicts my heuristic.

Comment: Will, I am not disputing your heuristic.  As long as we agree that it is not a proof, you can hope that it reflects what happens and I can worry that it does not.  The OEIS suggests that your heuristic does reflect what happens.  Gerhard "2B Could Actually Be 3B" Paseman, 2013.04.08

Comment: An idea to get past the $b$ lower bound - suppose there are $k$ different $n$-digit numbers, $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k$, with the stated property. Look at the values of $b \cdot n_i \mod (n + 1)$ and try to argue that if $k$ is large enough, there must be an $i$ such that $b \cdot n_i \mod (n+1) = (n+1)-m$ for $m = 0,1,2,\dots,b-1$. If we take $n = b$, that reduces to showing that not all the numbers have $b\cdot n_i = 1 \mod (b+1)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following links at the OEIS entry mentioned above takes one in a step or two to [this page](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/43769-Ponder-This) where there are posts (from 2005) with  Maple code and results out to base $23$. The values $N(b)$ for $2 \le b \le 23$ are reported to be

$2, 6, 7,  10, 11, 18, 17, 22, 25,  26, 28, 35, 39,  38, 39, 45, 48, 48,  52, 53, 56, 58$

Note that $N(7) \gt N(8)$ and $N(14) \gt N(15)$ and $N(19)=N(20).$

The ratios $\frac{N(b)}{b}$ are

$1.0, 2.0, 1.75, 2.0, 1.833, 2.571, 2.125, 2.444, 2.5, 2.364, 2.333, 2.692, $$2.786, 2.533, 2.438, 2.647, 2.667, 2.526, 2.60, 2.524, 2.546, 2.522$

Based on the data so far one might feel somewhat safe speculating that  $2\lt \frac{N(b)}{b} \lt 3$ provided $b \gt 6.$ As far as I can see, little nothing is known for sure (including that $N(b)$ is finite althoughthat seems highly likely.)

For each fixed value of $b$ there is a tree of possibilities (if we use a formal root node for level $0$.) A node at level $k-1$ has at most $\lceil \frac{b}{k}\rceil$ children. It might (or might not) be worth looking at the distribution of leaf levels.